# Apple SSO: Why I am getting a 'unsupported_grant_type' error?

Tags: ios, macos, oauth, single-sign-on

**Problem**

When i try to validate the `code` returned from the Apple SSO client flow, I keep getting a `unsupported_grant_type` 400 error.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/errorresponse) say that an `unsupported_grant_type` will be returned when `The authenticated client is not authorized to use the grant type.` I've enabled Apple SSO on the App Id, the Service Id, and have even verified my support email domains. What am I missing? Is there some other approval step I need to complete to get authorized?

I've tried removing params from my verification request, but still get the same error code.

**Details**

The SSO redirect gives me a form-encoded POST body that looks something like this: `{"state"=>"x", "code"=>"y", "id_token"=>"z"}`.

I then attempt to validate the token by calling `validate_auth_token`.

```rb
   def validate_auth_token(token, is_refresh = false)
      uri = URI.parse('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token')
      https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      https.use_ssl = true
      headers = { 'Content-Type': 'text/json' }
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, headers)
      request_body = {
        client_id: @client_id,
        client_secret: retreive_client_secret
      }

      if is_refresh
        request_body[:grant_type] = 'refresh_token'
        request_body[:refresh_token] = token
      else
        request_body[:grant_type] = 'authorization_code'
        request_body[:code] = token
        request_body[:redirect_uri] = "https://#{Rails.application.secrets.backend_host_port}/apple"
      end

      request.body = request_body.to_json
      response = https.request(request)
      p JSON.parse response.body
    end

    def retreive_client_secret
      cert = retreive_secret_cert
      ecdsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new cert
      algorithm = 'ES256'

      headers = {
        'alg': algorithm,
        'kid': @key_id
      }

      claims = {
        'iss': @team_id,
        'iat': Time.now.to_i,
        'exp': Time.now.to_i + 5.months.to_i,
        'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub': @client_id
      }

      token = JWT.encode claims, ecdsa_key, algorithm, headers
      token
    end
```

Where @client_id is the "Service ID" I submitted in the initial SSO request, @key_id is the id of the private key downloaded from the apple key dashboard, and @team_id is our apple team id. `retrieve_secret_cert` simply gets the cert file body used to generate the client secret.

Given all this, I would expect a [TokenResponse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/tokenresponse), but keep getting the same error `{"error"=>"unsupported_grant_type"}` with no additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token validation request needs to be *form* encoded, not *json* encoded. Also, the request wasn't validating correctly when I included an `alg` header in the JWT, but worked after I removed it.

Here's the updated code:

```rb
    def validate_auth_token(token, is_refresh = false)
      uri = URI.parse('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token')
      https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      https.use_ssl = true
      request_body = {
        client_id: @client_id,
        client_secret: retreive_client_secret
      }

      if is_refresh
        request_body[:grant_type] = 'refresh_token'
        request_body[:refresh_token] = token
      else
        request_body[:grant_type] = 'authorization_code'
        request_body[:code] = token
        request_body[:redirect_uri] = "https://#{Rails.application.secrets.backend_host_port}/auth"
      end

      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
      request.set_form_data(request_body)

      response = https.request(request)
      JSON.parse response.body
    end

    def retreive_client_secret
      cert = retreive_secret_cert
      ecdsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new cert
      algorithm = 'ES256'

      headers = {
        'kid': @key_id
      }

      claims = {
        'iss': @team_id,
        'iat': Time.now.to_i,
        'exp': Time.now.to_i + 5.minutes.to_i,
        'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub': @client_id
      }

      token = JWT.encode claims, ecdsa_key, algorithm, headers
      token
    end
```

Thank you [sudhakar19](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/381552#381552) for pointing out the encoding error.